# When Dialog is appear or dismiss in Activity, Which Activity Lifecycle method is called

Tags: android

When Dialog is Appear - onPause() method is called.
When Dialog is dimiss - onResume() method is called.

But in my below example it is not worked.Please Look my below code and clear my confusion.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView txtName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    txtName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);

    txtName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCustomDialog();
        }
    });
}

public void showCustomDialog(){
// Create custom dialog object
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
// Include dialog.xml file
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
// Set dialog title
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

// set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
text.setText("Custom dialog Android example.");
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

dialog.show();

Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
// if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Close dialog
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("MainActivity","onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e("MainActivity","onPause");
}
```

onPuase() is not called when dialog appear.
onResume() is not called when dialog dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html

The dialog is not being tied to the lifecycle of the Activity. onPause and onResume will be called when the activity is in those states, not when the dialog is in a state. 
For example, if you were to put a dialog.dismiss() when your Activity goes onPause, you will see that when you come onResume your dialog will no longer be there.